# MERGE INTO Performance

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance, sql-merge

I have a table contains tat contains {service_id, service_name,region_name}

As input my procedure gets service_id , i_svc_region list of key,value pairs, which has  {service_name, region}.

Have to insert into the table if the record does not exists already. I know it is a very simple query.. But does the below queries make any difference in performance?

which one is better and why?

```
MERGE INTO SERVICE_REGION_MAP table1
USING 
    (SELECT i_svc_region(i).key as service_name,i_enabled_regions(i).value as region
         FROM dual) table2
ON (table1.service_id =i_service_id and table1.region=table2.region)    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN       
    INSERT (service_id,service_name ,region) VALUES (i_service_id ,table2.service_name,table2.region);
```

i_service_id  - is passed as it is.

```
MERGE INTO SERVICE_REGION_MAP table1
USING 
    (SELECT i_service_id as service_id, i_svc_region(i).key as service_name,i_enabled_regions(i).value as region
         FROM dual) table2
ON (table1.service_id =table2.service_id and table1.region=table2.region)    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN       
    INSERT (service_id,service_name ,region) VALUES (table2.service_id,table2.service_name,table2.region);
```

i_service_id is considered as column in table.

Does this really make any difference?

Comment: It's unlikely to make any appreciable difference. However, if I were you and the rest of the code made it possible, I would do my best to try and get all the merges done in one go - i.e. rather than looping over the array, I would select from the array (after making the array type global via `create or replace type ...`), if it's not already global) instead and do all the merging in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the FORALL statement. It will result in much faster performance than any looping we could write. Check out the documenation, starting with https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321

Answer (score 0):

As @Brian Leach suggests the FORALL will give you a single round trip to SQL engine for all of the elements (i's) in your table. This *can* give between 10 and 100 times improvement depending on table size and many other things beyond me.

Also you are only using the INSERT capability of MERGE so a time honoured INSERT statement should make life easier/faster for the database. MERGE has more bells and whistles which can slow it down.

So try something like:

`FORALL i IN 1..i_svc_region(i).COUNT
  INSERT INTO SERVICE_REGION_MAP table1
  (service_id, service_name, region)
  SELECT
    i_service_id AS service_id, 
    i_svc_region(i).KEY AS service_name, 
    i_enabled_regions(i).VALUE AS region
  FROM DUAL table2
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM SERVICE_REGION_MAP table1
        WHERE table1.service_id=table2.service_id AND table1.region=table2.region
      );`